# ajax wont execute php function

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to create a login form with ajax, but the php event handler never start, if i use the METHOD POST form, the function works without a problem.

I have debugg the function, and the ajax form is sending httprequest.

Any ideas?

this is my ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function() { 
        var login_email = $('#login_email').val();
        var login_password = $('#login_password').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'core/manageusers.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            login:login_email,
                login_email:login_email,
                login_password:login_password

            },
                success: function() {
                location.reload();
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Eventhandler.

```
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) 
    {   

        include_once('core/class.users.php');
    $email = $_POST['login_email'];
    $password = $_POST['login_password'];

}
```

Comment: Try to debug your code. First of all look through Mozilla Firebug or Google Chrome Developer tools (Network section) if the HTTP request is sent.

Comment: default method in form is get.

Comment: @zavg yes sorry, i forgot to mention it, the request is being send and the values to.

Comment: Is `core/manageusers.php` the correct url value?

Comment: add var_dump($_POST) in manageusers.php and see what it gives you.

Comment: @boom_Shiva I only get array 0.

Comment: in your isset function you are looking for $_POST['login'] but do not declare that variable in your ajax, try using this format for parameter passing data: "login_email=" +login_email+ "&login_password=" +login_password,

Answer (score 0):

```
 login:login_email,
                login_email:login_email,
                login_password:login_password   ,

            },
```

That wayward comma at the end of `login_password:login_password` will break it, but probably not your only problem

Comment: as you said its not the only problem. noting seems to change when i remove the comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove ',' from the end of  'login_password:login_password     ,'
```

Comment: This will only break IE, not FF, prove.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in the creation of ajax request :

```
data: {
       login:login_email,
       login_email:login_email,
       login_password:login_password **,**

            },
```

remove this comma

Answer (score 0):

Works as designed: If you are retrieving Data in PHP with `$_POST`, nothing will happen if you are accessing with a `GET` Request.

The AJAX actually sends POST as from your code above.